# jQuery Plugin Need: Marquee Text with Direction Control with Mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, scroll, marquee, sliding

I am searching a jQuery plugin to marquee text in a div and control the direction with mouse. I've found one [example](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm) which is written in pure Javascipt.

The plugin must have these functionalities:

- Start scrolling on mouse hover
- Scrolling direction must be change by muse movements.

It would be great if scrolling speed also change with mouse movements.

Comment: Why do you want a jQuery plugin? jQuery is just a layer above JavaScript, so what's the problem with just using the linked script?

Comment: I want to use it as a plugin, so i can give this feature any element with class: "marqueeText" on my page. The example script needs an ID to work. Maybe modifying the exmaple script need my meet.